# Equivalent of Mockito any with not null constraint

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I am writing test cases from last few days. I want to know is there any equivalent of `org.mockito.Matchers.any` with not null constraint?

I mean if you say:

```
when(reviewBuilder.saveReviewModel(any())).thenReturn(2L);
```

Then `saveReviewModel` can take any objects including `null`. Is there a way to pass only not null objects to a method using Mockito 1.10.19 library?

Comment: It is Mockito 1.10.19.

Answer (score 4):

You can write your custom matcher that will pass this condition.

```
 class NotNullObjects extends ArgumentMatcher<Review> {
     public boolean matches(Object object) {
         return object!=null;
     }
 }
```

Then usage

```
when(reviewBuilder.saveReviewModel(argThat(new NotNullObjects()))).thenReturn(2L);
```

My one advice is to think of some interface that you can expect there as na input of your method.

Answer (score 4):

In Mockito 1.9.5 there are [isNotNull()](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/org/mockito/Matchers.html#isNotNull()) and [isNotNull(java.lang.Class clazz)](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/org/mockito/Matchers.html#isNotNull(java.lang.Class)) which do the null check.

From version 2.1.0 anyX() and any(SomeType.class) matchers reject nulls and check type. See [Incompatible changes with 1.10](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#incompatible-changes-with-110) paragraph on **What's new in Mockito 2** page.

Answer (score 1):

This works if you specify the expected type of the parameter in the `verify` method call:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnit;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoRule;

public class MockitoNotNullTest {

    private static class Dependency1 {

    }

    private static class Dependency2 {
        public void doesNotAcceptNull(Dependency1 d) {

        }
    }

    private static class ClassUnderTest {
        private final Dependency2 d2;

        public ClassUnderTest(Dependency2 d2) {
            this.d2 = d2;
        }

        public void passesNull() {
            d2.doesNotAcceptNull(null);
        }

    }

    @Rule
    public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
    @Mock
    Dependency2 d2;

    @Test
    public void passesNull_callsD1WithNull_verifyFails() {
        ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(d2);

        classUnderTest.passesNull();

        // fails as expected
        Mockito.verify(d2).doesNotAcceptNull(Mockito.any(Dependency1.class));
    }

}
```

and the result is:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
d2.doesNotAcceptNull(
    <any stackoverflow.MockitoNotNullTest.Dependency1>
);
-> at stackoverflow.MockitoNotNullTest.passesNull_callsD1WithNull_verifyFails(MockitoNotNullTest.java:48)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
d2.doesNotAcceptNull(
    null
);
-> at stackoverflow.MockitoNotNullTest$ClassUnderTest.passesNull(MockitoNotNullTest.java:32)

    // ...
```